# Does a chart always have an atlas containing it?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I've been reading "An Introduction to Manifolds" by Loring Tu and have some questions to which I cannot find answers. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

It says for dimension < 4 every topological manifold $M$ has a unique differentiable structure, but that should not necessarily mean a chart ($U_p$,$\Phi_p$) about a point $p$ in a manifold always has an atlas $\{$($U_\alpha$,$\Phi_\alpha)$} in which it is contained. Is there any example of a chart near a point in a manifold that cannot be contained in an atlas?

Also, if there are more than 1 differentiable structures, are we justified in making a specific choice of them when dealing with differentiation, integration, etc. in manifolds? Don't we need to show 'differentiable structure - invariance' of those properties as we did for parametrization-invariance for length, curvature of curves?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: A (smooth) manifold is, by **definition**, the data of a topological manifold and a smooth atlas on it. Integration, differentiation, etc. are differentiable notions. Of course they depend on the differentiable structure ! But the same topological manifold with two different differentiable structures are two different smooth manifolds. There is no need to prove any "differentiable strcutrue invariance".

Comment: Thank you, It greatly resolved my curiosity. Much appreciated.